# Why the address number is not equal in dec and in hex?

Tags: c

```
debian@debian:~$ cat  /tmp/test.c
#include<stdio.h> 
int  main(void)
{
 int m=1;
 printf("m=%d\n",&m);
 printf("m=%p\n",&m);
}
debian@debian:~$ gcc  /tmp/test.c -o  /tmp/test.exe
debian@debian:~$ /tmp/test.exe
m=-1078061268
m=0xbfbe172c
debian@debian:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print hex(-1078061268)
-0x4041e8d4
```

why the `-1078061268` in dec is not equal `0xbfbe172c` in hex?

Comment: those numbers are equal. a hex value looks different from an unsigned int because of the sign attribute and the different bases (16 vs 10).

Comment: Besides your problem of identifying the decimal versus hex pattern, you have a more severe problem. Never ever print a pointer with `%d`. Integers and pointers often have different width, so `printf` will mix up its parameters badly, crashing your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same, you're comparing signed to unsigned.

take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) at the formats.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int  main(void)
{
   int m=1;
   printf("m=%u\n",&m);  // 3219008780
   printf("m=%p\n",&m);  // 0xbfde2d0c
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is. in 2's complement.

```
>>> hex(2**32-1078061268)
'0xbfbe172c'
```

An address is not an int. if your machine is 32bit, it is an unsigned int (in fact, `uint32_t`). if not, it is a `uint64_t`. it is always safe to put it in a `uintptr_t`, and print it with `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

The first printf statement is treating the address as a signed integer. The second is treating it is a pointer (which, for printf, amounts to printing it out as an unsigned hex number). Those two numbers have the same binary representation in two's complement arithmetic, although they are not numerically equal. This is why comparisons between signed and unsigned values are a bad idea.