# How computer compare two number in bottom layer?

Tags: c

I have written code like follow:

```
int a = -1;
unsigned int b = 0xffffffff;

if (a == b)
    printf("a == b\n");
else
    printf("a != b\n");

printf("a = %x b = %x\n", a, b);
return 0;
```

And the result is as follow:
[image]

It shows that a and b are equal. So I want to know how the computer make this judgement?

Comment: Are you asking how a computer does integer comparisons or how `-1` is the same as `0xffffffff` (in this case)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the address number is not equal in dec and in hex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878650/why-the-address-number-is-not-equal-in-dec-and-in-hex)

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2085031/3436922)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any arithmetic operation with a signed integer **a** and unsigned integer **b** as operands, **a** will be implicitly cast to unsigned. Since `-1` signed *in this case* is `0xffffffff` unsigned, **a** and **b** compares equal.

Answer (score 1):

The machine representation of your two values `a` and `b` is the same bit pattern (on your particular computer and implementation), so the `a == b` test is true.

BTW, you should enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). You'll probably get some warnings, because you probably has hit some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And you could run your code step by step in your debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and query the values (and their machine representations).